# Wrong date in contract for salary raise potentially in my favor

Tags: salary, raise, salaried-pay

Around two months ago I was given a raise at work which took effect at the start of 2021. However looking at the paperwork again I noticed that the start date given for the raise to take effect was wrong. Instead of 01.01.2021 it said 01.01.2020.

My question is how to best proceed from here?
Should I just let it go as it's a very obvious clerical error or should I ask they pay me what amounts to about a months salary?

Comment: If you were a manager, how would you treat an employee who noticed a clerical error, and then demanded to be paid the difference in salary?  If it were me,  I would fire that employee -  if I worked in a situation where firing was difficult (union rules, strong laws against this) they would forever be moved into the "bad" list (no promotions, raises, etc.).

Answer (score 16):

> *My question is how to best proceed from here?*

Send an email pointing out the mistake, and get it corrected.

This is not high school, where we can try finding loopholes (to exploit). Wear your professional hat, accept what is intended.

Comment: I like the email approach. If they say not to worry about it, then at least you have a paper trail of their response.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I just let it go as it's a very obvious clerical error or should I ask they pay me what amounts to about a months salary?

Can you list what country you're in? In the USA, and possibly other 1st world countries, there are numerous case laws in regard to incorrect pay due to paperwork error.

The general ruling is, unless your boss initially made a mistake and you both agreed with it, then you're going to have to pay back anything that you took out once they find out the error. If you have auto deposit, they do have the right to reverse the charge once they find the error. If your bank account has it withdrawn or transferred, then you'll likely get a notice from your bank and the company.

So my advice is to bring the error up immediately and if you do happen to find a very large bank deposit, do not spend it on anything so they can reverse the charge.